# Application is closed if we minimized the app in iphone -That is good way for development

Tags: iphone

```
If App is MINIMIZED?  (It currently logs out).
```

What is required by Apple?  What is a best practice?

Do we have the option of either keeping the App logged in or logged out upon minimization?
Please say.... which option is best ?

I working in an application and my first view is about login details. But if i minimise or i can run other app than also the first app is running in the background but it starts from the first view.
My question is that normally if we can minimise app than it starts from last view only. But in my app it starts from first view means Login View. So if app is minimise it is good to starts from first view. Please say…..

Comment: Huh what? What kind of "login" are you talking about?

Comment: Login means Main page of the Application where we can login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. iOS app doesn't closes when you pres the home button(minimized). It goes in background. And you can run it again in same state it was minimized.
2. I'm guessing first page of your application is login screen. This is your decision. If you app is about Finance or it has some data which need to be secure from others. It's better to log out user when your app mimimized.
3. If you app doesn't have any data which can't be tempered then you can keep user logged in. However, this is your decision.
4. Apple doesn't has any guideline about what you should do when your app is minimized.